# USB C to USB A female

Tags: usb, usb-c, otg

Hi guys I need some help I have got a new phone that's USB C and I need to make an OTG adapter. I have a USB C end that's got a circuit board with two little chips in it that I tried to test and I believe they're 56k. I know the easy thing would be just to buy an adapter but in my circumstances I can't buy one now and I need to make one I looked all day for a 5.1k resistor I couldn't find none on all my junk circuit boards is there any way I can remove the 56k chips or ground A5 and my phone will be the host I don't care about getting any power to the peripherals. I just need to transfer some data to a thumb drive and some music to an MP3 player I had no problem doing this with my old phone that was a micro USB all I did was short out the 4th pin but this USB C is a different animal

Comment: `I believe they're 56k` .. 56k what?

Comment: Surface mount resistor

Comment: Chips normally refer to ICs or more specifically the silicon wafers inside them.

Comment: Please use some punctuation.

Comment: Sorry about the punctuation and calling something by the wrong name but you know this question was asked and answered before y'all put you two cents worth in.

Answer (score 2):

Use resistors in series or parallel or series parallel in order to get the correct resistance you need, then solder that on. It doesn't need to be on the board just connected to it by some wire.

Yes you would remove the 56k resistors between vbus/power and CC1/CC2. Then place the combination of resistors that make 5.1k between cc1 or cc2 and ground. You only need on, but the cable will only work in one orientation.

Finally the resistor has a tolerance. It can be 20% up or down for your purpose, or 10% for power detection. That means 4 to 6k should be okay.

Comment: Thank you for the information can I just put a drop of solder or a jumper on both ends of the 56k resistor and do I do both resistors or just the one.

Comment: You probably want to remove them completely. So you have access to traces connected to cc1 and cc2.